# Question about the top of a bound representation of a bound quiver.

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I am reading the book [Elements of the Representation Theory of Associative Algebras: Volume 1](http://books.google.com.hk/books/about/Elements_of_the_Representation_Theory_of.html?id=ayNHpi3tYhQC).

I have a on page 77. In (d) of Lemma 2.2 on Page 77, it is said that $$ L_a=\sum_{\alpha: a\to b} \operatorname{Coker}(\psi_{\alpha}: M_b \to M_a). $$

I think that $L_a$ should be $$ L_a=\cap_{\alpha: a\to b} \operatorname{Coker}(\varphi_{\alpha}: M_b \to M_a). $$

Is this true? Thank you very much.[image]

Comment: Do you mean cokernel?

Comment: @Jim, yes. I will edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither intersecting nor summing different cokernels really makes much sense.  Both those operations require that there is a larger space to do the intersection/summation in.

In this case what they mean is that $L_a = M_a/J_a$ where $J_a$ is defined in (c).